# How can I add configurations from one bundle to another in Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, configuration, bundle

I found PrependExtensionInterface in [the dropzone-symfony-ux-bundle](https://github.com/symfony/ux-dropzone/blob/main/DependencyInjection/DropzoneExtension.php) and thought it could be usefull for following problem: I want to add paths to security.access_control like they do with twig and themes. So I tried:

```
    public function prepend(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $bundles = $container->getParameter('kernel.bundles');

        if (isset($bundles['SecurityBundle'])) {
            $config = $this->processConfiguration(new Configuration(), $container->getExtensionConfig('security'));
            $config['access_control'][] = ['path' => '^my/new/path', 'role' =>'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'];
            $container->prependExtensionConfig('security', $config);
        }
    }
```

But I get an error with processConfiguration() telling me that all the keys in security are unknown und shows me known keys from my bundle:

```
Unrecognized options "providers, role_hierarchy, encoders, firewalls" under "<name of my bundle>". Available options are ... (keys from my bundle configuration)
```

If I test it with twig instead of security I get the same error but with twig keywords (obvious). All I do different to UX-Dropzone is that my Bundle has a Configuration class in DependencyInfection.

Any idear what I do wrong? Or better a working solution?

UPDATE:

```
    public function prepend(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $bundles = $container->getParameter('kernel.bundles');

        if (isset($bundles['SecurityBundle'])) {
            $securityExtension = new SecurityExtension();
            $securityExtension->prepend($container);
            $securityExtension->load([], $container);
            $configuration = $securityExtension->getConfiguration([],$container);
            $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $container->getExtensionConfig('security'));
            $config['access_control'][] = ['path' => '^my/new/path', 'role' =>'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'];
            $container->prependExtensionConfig('security', $config);
        }
    }
```

Now I have used the right Configuration but i do not get it working:

```
Unrecognized options "anonymous, guard, remember_me" under "security.firewalls.main". Available options are "access_denied_handler", "access_denied_url", "context", "entry_point", "host", "logout", "logout_on_user_change", "methods", "pattern", "provider", "request_matcher", "security", "stateless", "switch_user", "user_checker".
```

I guess I missed some factories but I can not reengineer the whole security bundle for this...

Comment: it is behaving like that because the `Configuration` class you are loading is from your bundle instead of the Security bundle. A better question to consider is why are you trying to do this? Probably there is a better solution. Take a look in the Security bundle and see what parameters it publishes and perhaps you can get the value you need from that.

Comment: Thx. I understand. Unfortunately  to instanciate the Configuration of the Security bundle you need two additional Objects, I do not have. So this solution does not work for security but perhaps for other bundles with a normal configuration object.

Comment: Is there another generic solution to add values or set default values in the configuration of  a foreign bundle from your own bundle?

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/prepend_extension.html